# Parsing 20 digits number on PHP

Tags: php, parsing, int, double, digits

Want to ask about how to keep 20digits number on PHP?

This is the example:

```
<?php 
echo 5100199999999999999;
echo '<br>';
echo floatval(5100199999999999999);
echo '<br>';
echo number_format(5100199999999999999, 0,'','');
echo '<br>';
echo number_format(5100111111111111111, 0,'','');
```

---

This is what i got:

```
5.1002E+18
5.1002E+18
5100200000000000000
5100111111111110656
```

How to keep it the exact value?

Comment: why not make it a string?

Comment: You _might_ be interested in the php extensions [bcmath](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) and/or [gmp](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).

Comment: @Dagon cannot, the schema allow only number.

Comment: @VolkerK Hi bro, can add this as an answer? bcmul() works!

Comment: So, you really want to do calculations with those numbers ... ;-) (It was only a wild guess.)

Comment: nope, this is only for unique id that last for the rest of my life hahaha @VolkerK

Comment: Oh, then this is a bit offtopic regarding your question (as stated): You might be interested in [rfc 4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) and [rfc-4122-uuid](https://github.com/macx/rfc-4122-uuid). Like IPv6 those are 128bit ids, supposed to be enough for the whole solar system ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK Hi, when i var_dump, its still string. not number/integer. i was wrong T_T

Comment: Yes, bcmath uses strings as the "transport medium" ;-) What did you expect and why is this a problem?

Comment: i need the value to be long/double when the value is 20digits @VolkerK

Comment: @VolkerK var_dump(bcmul("11111111111111111111", "1")); the result is string(20) "11111111111111111111"

Comment: Please elaborate on "i need the value to be long/double". Why exactly do you need gettype($var) to be long/float?

Comment: btw: a) consider `echo PHP_INT_MAX, "\r\n", '11111111111111111111';`, the range of an integer/long is magnitudes smaller than your number. b) php's IEEE 754 double precision "float" has a precision of ~ 16 decimal places; also way smaller than your number. So, both types are out of the question.

Comment: @VolkerK because it should be the unique id with auto increment on my case. and i am using php to get the value. thats why i need the rational number.

Comment: Sorry, still don't see the need for the type to be long/float. "unique id with auto increment" you mean you have a DECIMAL/BIGINT in a _MySQL_ table? Assigning a string will do nicely, MySQL's type system can handle that. You might also be interested in MySQL's (UUID())[http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid].

Comment: @VolkerK i see now, but i stuck with the schema that it should be type="long" on another apps

Comment: no way, dude ;-)  Even a 64bit signed long/llong can't hold `11111111111111111111` `>` `9223372036854775807` (php int is always signed)

Comment: and btw: "on another apps" - that doesn't hinder php from sending the number as a string to MySQL (I still assume there's MySQL involved because of " id with auto increment" - that's MySQL jargon ;-)).

Comment: @VolkerK hahaha mind blowing, i know now. there was misinformation they said another apps can handle 63 digits of unique number, and now have correction that the value is 63bit and it's not even higher than int(2147483647) on 32bit system. so this problem solved with that misinformation. thank you VolkerK to accompany me to solve this problem. i appreciate it!!

Answer (score -1):

You can try it like string and convert it every time. If it numbers contains dot, 888.9999999, you can divide by the count number before the dot, in this case by 7: for example: 8889999999 / 10000000.

I hope help you.